# What does the letter U mean in math?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What does the letter U mean in the following expression:
$$
\bigcup_{\alpha} A_\alpha \;?
$$

It doesn't look like logical OR.

Link to original [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6DNK.jpg).

Comment: The question has already been answered, but let's throw in the [Wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_of_sets) for good measure. Notice in particular that finite unions are in a very precise sense analogous to [disjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) -- the "logical OR".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It represents the union of all the sets $A_\alpha$. By the "union", what it basically means that:

$$ a \in \bigcup_{\alpha}  A_\alpha \iff \exists \alpha :a \in A_\alpha $$

or in words - it is the set of elements which are contained in any of the $A_\alpha$.

Comment: That $\Rightarrow$ should be a $\Longleftrightarrow$, no?

Comment: Also, it is perhaps pertinent to point out that the notation $\coprod$ is often used to denote the "disjoint product". That is, same definition, but it is only used when the $A_{\alpha}$ have pairwise trivial intersection: $A_{\alpha}\cap A_{\beta}=\emptyset$ for $\alpha\neq \beta$.

Comment: I originally put that, but for some reason I wasn't too sure whether I should or not - I'll change it to the $\iff$. As for the disjoint product, it can also be denoted by dots above the union sign, for example: $A_\alpha \dot{\cup} A_\beta $ for when the two have trivial intersection.

Comment: @user1729 IIRC, disjoint product is a bit different than you describe. Set theoretically $\coprod_{i\in I} A_i = \{(a,i) \in \left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\right) \times I \mid a \in A_i\} = \bigcup_{i \in I} \left(A_i \times \{i\}\right)$, the idea being that the $A_i$ might not be disjoint, but $A_i \times \{i\}$ *is* disjoint from $A_j \times \{j\}$ when $i \neq j$.

Comment: @user1729 here's a $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ tip: Use `\implies`, `\impliedby` and `\iff` instead of the needlessly long `\Longleftrightarrow` and friends.

Comment: @kahen According to wikipedia, there are [two definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union)! (I was starting to doubt all I know...). Also, out of interest, how did you know I used \Longleftrightarrow?

Comment: @user1729 you can right click any math and use "show math as => TeX commands" to pop up a window with the source.